# Apollo graphql remote schema extending is dependent on remote fields

Tags: graphql, apollo

We are able to extend our remote schema, but with one major caveat: the new field cannot be queried for on it's own; it must be included with at least one field from the remote.  Is it possible to query for just the extended field?

In the example below, I have extended "name" to include the field "catsName."  If I query for "first," the query works.  If I query for "catsName" and "first," the query works.  If I query for just "catsName," it returns an internal server error with status code 400.

Note :
- When we extend non-remote fields, we do not have this issue. 
- Our remote GraphQL engine uses Absinthe (Erlang/Elixir).  We use Apollo locally.  Our goal is to support the legacy Absinthe GraphQL implementation.

**Working Query :**

```
query{
    user{
        profile{
            personal{
                name{   // extend type name
                     catsName // New field
                     first    // Original field 
}}}}}
```

**Non-working Query :**

```
query{
    user{
        profile{
            personal{
                name{   // extend type name
                     catsName // New field
}}}}}
```

**Error :**

> "message": "Field \"name\" of type \"UserPersonalName\" must have a 
>    selection of subfields. Did you mean \"name { ... }\"?"

After further research we determined that the reason for this is that user, profile, personal, and name exist on the remote server.  The extension of "catsName" exists locally.  If we query for just catsName, our engine has no way of knowing that the root fields exist, and therefore returns an error.  If we include at least one remote field in our query, the local engine knows to fetch the remote and is able to return all of the data.